# Plotting predicted effect of interaction term on dependent variable in glm logistic regression model (using R)

Tags: r, plot, glm, predict, interaction

I'm currently analyzing survey data in R, fitting a logistic regression model that features interaction terms. For sake of reproducibility, I shortened and simplified the data I'm working with. It can be downloaded straight forward via [google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GPR-ZwCUTQG_47oaFhfOeiHUBme99O_M/view?usp=sharing).

The data (`dat`) consists of a dummy dependent variable `y` (dummy), some dummy independent variables `x1:3`, a mediator `m` and a weight `wgt`.

Once you have the csv-file, you can simply copy and paste the script below:

```
library(foreign)
dat<-read.csv("~/dat.csv") #fill in path

fit<-glm(data=dat,y ~ x1*m + x2*m + x3*m, family=quasibinomial(link="logit"), weights=wgt, na.action=na.exclude)

summary(fit)
BaylorEdPsych::PseudoR2(fit)
```

You will notice that one interaction term is sig (p<0.05) while this other two are not, even though one gets close (p<0.1).

What I need now is to visualize the results. Specifically, I need a plot that shows how `x2` in interaction with `m` impacts on `Pr(y)`. When I'm thinking about linear regression I would have an image of two lines (plus CIs) in mind. However, in this case of a logistic regression and an interaction effect, I'm not quite sure. What would be the appropriate way of plotting this interaction effect and how would this be done technically? I would be really thankful, if someone could walk me through.

Is there a way to use {ggplot2} and {effects} for plotting or do I need something else?

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, this is the easiest way to get the desired plot, even including confidence intervals. But I'm still lwondering whether this is a) appropriate for logistic regression models and b) why it's so darn complicated to get this using {ggplot2}.

```
library(jtools)
interact_plot(fit, pred="x2", modx="m", interval=T, int.width=0.95)
#Note on the use of this: Don't transform variables *within* your model, such as `as.factor(...)`. Apparently, the `jtools` functions cannot handel those.
```

Comment: Btw, I tried to provide a way in which the data can be loaded in R directly from google drive, but didn't quite succeed. `read.csv("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GPR-ZwCUTQG_47oaFhfOeiHUBme99O_M/view?usp=sharing")` didn't work.

Comment: For plotting, I already tried `dat$pred<-predict(fit,se.fit = F, type="response")`
`ggplot(dat, aes(x=x2, y=pred, color=m))+geom_line()` as well as a couple of other things, but it didn't quite work.